# How do i calculate correlation between variable v of length n = 20 with m other variables (where m ranges from 1 to 100)

Tags: r, loops, correlation

I have one variable v of length 20 that i wish to correlate with m other variables. For all m between 1 and 100, compute the distribution for the maximum absolute correlation coefficient between v and each of the other m variables, assuming the variables are independent.

In addition, i am required to find the probability of getting a maximum absolute correlation above 0.4

This is what i had tried so far. I am confused about how to run a loop to calculate the coefficient for a range of number of variables from 1 to 100 and saving the coefficient value with the corresponding m value of variables.

However, i get an error message: Error in cor(v, m_norm) : incompatible dimensions In addition, set.seed does not ensure i get the same results when i run the code

```
set.seed(42) # default set by the question

v <- rnorm (20) # length of variable v

nrun <- 100 # to run m from 1 to 100 to generate variables
m <- numeric(nrun)


# I want to calculate the max abs correlation coefficient between v 
# and each of the other m variables (where m takes on values from 1
# 100)

for ( i in 1: nrun) {

m_norm <- rnorm(m)
m[i] <- cor(v, m_norm)

}

# Find the frequency of the correlation coefficients > 0.4
sum(abs(cor(max(m)) > 0.4 / nrun

# Plot m on the x axis and frequency of correlation 
# coefficients >0.4 on the y axis
plot ( m = 1:100, sum(abs(cor(max(m)) > 0.4 / nrun)
```

I am supposed to get 100 maximum abs coefficient values when i calculate correlation between variable v with m (which ranges 1 to 100) variables. I am to find the probability and frequency of getting a max abs correlation above 0.4, in addition plot frequency against m.

Comment: Correlation coefficient is defined for variables of the same length. So when you generate `m_norm`, it needs to have the same length as `v`. But instead of `m_norm <- rnorm(length(v))`, you use `rnorm(m)`, where `m` is the vector you're storing the correlation results. Change `rnorm(m)` to `rnorm(length(v))` and your code should work. (Voting to close as typo.)

Comment: If you're careful about running `set.seed()` and re-initializing variables (clearing any saved values), you will get identical results every time you run the code. If you're not seeing that, you must be accidentally re-using some values from the previous run.

Comment: Lastly, to avoid problems like this in the future, I'd strongly recommend better variable names. `nrun` is a great name, but `m` is a poor name. Something like `result` or `correlations` would be much clearer, and make a bug like this less likely.

Comment: The first argument to `rnorm` is the number of samples you want returned.  So in your loop, how many elements are you getting from `rnorm(m)`? Try running through your loop manually. I.e. set `i <- 1` and then run each line of code.

Comment: `v <- rnorm (20);
nrun <- 100;
m <- replicate(nrun, cor(v, rnorm(length(v))))`

Comment: However, v is defined to have a length of n = 20, and i am supposed to correlated with m other variables (m ranges from 1 to 100), i am still confused on how this works.